# Asymptotic behaviour for an integral with parameter $n$

Tags: integration, equivalence-relations

I am trying to find an asymptotic development up to the precision $o(1)$ for the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} ne^{-nt}\left (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{t^k}{k!}\right)^n\text{d}t$ as $n\longrightarrow +\infty$... but I do not manage either to find an equivalent. ..
Many thanks if you have some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_n(t)=e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{t^k}{k!}$: the given integral is $\int_{0}^{+\infty}n g_n(t)^n\,dt $ and

$$ g_n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^j t^{j+k}}{j! k!}=1-\frac{t^n}{n!}+\frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n-1)!}+O(t^{n+2}). $$
$g_n(t)$ is related to a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution): it is well-known that the law of large numbers implies $\lim_{n\to +\infty}g_n(n)=\frac{1}{2}$, and in general we have
$$ g_n(t) \approx \frac{1}{2}\left[1-\operatorname{Erf}\left(\frac{t-n}{\sqrt{2n}}\right)\right]=\frac{1}{2}\,\operatorname{Erfc}\left(\frac{t-n}{\sqrt{2n}}\right)$$
so $\int_{0}^{+\infty}n g_n(t)^n\,dt$ roughly behaves like $\frac{2n^2}{e}$ for moderately large values of $n$, but in order to derive the asymptotic expansion up to the $o(1)$ term we need a pretty heavy machinery, like [the Berry-Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) and refined versions of the [Laplace method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method). What is the purpose of finding such asymptotic expansion?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The integral is equal to the average number of drawings which are necessary to empty for the first time an urn when we consider n urns, each one containing n balls. I would like to understand this number with sharpness...at least find an equivalent using alalysis arguments.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not see how you get $\frac{2n^2}e$. I am able to show that $\displaystyle g_n(t)=\sqrt 2\frac{n^{n-1/2} e^{-n}}{(n-1)!}\int_{\frac {t-n}{\sqrt {2n}}}^\infty e^{-s\sqrt{2n}}(1+s\sqrt{\frac 2n})^{n-1} ds $ which only leads to $ g_n $ converges to 1... but after? Thank you.